# Quaqua look and feel issues

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, quaqua

I am using quaqua look and feel in linux and windows. it was working fine till I got the problem witn JOptionPane. When the code opens the JOptionPane using the line

```
JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(
    pos_main.category_layer, "Give Rewards Now!!", "Loyalty", 1);
```

I am getting the following exception,

```
Warning: class ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXApplication couldn't load library "quaqua". 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no quaqua in java.library.path
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1074)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:927)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.createInternalFrame(JOptionPane.java:1541)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:1259)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:1194)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:1155)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:1118)
    at operator.pos_main.formWindowOpened(pos_main.java:254)
    at operator.pos_main.access$000(pos_main.java:38)
    at operator.pos_main$1.windowOpened(pos_main.java:79)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(AWTEventMulticaster.java:322)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:1859)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:279)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:1820)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

--EDIT--

System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); shows the following output.

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_15\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\DecisionStudio Professional\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\DecisionStudio Professional\R-Project\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\GmoteServer\bin\vlc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to check through the steps for [*Integration Into an Application*](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/index.html).

Addendum: On Mac OS X, `/System/Library/Java` is the root of several system properties, such as `java.home` and `java.library.path`. It's where the resources required for `JOptionPane` live. Linux and Windows are [not supported](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/).

Addendum: On Ubuntu 10.04, the `JOptionPane` demo runs fine; you can use this [approach](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/laf.html), which is suitable for development purposes only.

```
$ java -jar dist/quaqua-test.jar 
   CREATING LAF   ch.randelshofer.quaqua.leopard.Quaqua15LeopardCrossPlatformLookAndFeel
   LAF CREATED   
   SETTING LAF  
   LAF SET   
QuaquaTest EDT latency=203
QuaquaTest laf create latency=69
QuaquaTest set laf latency=46
QuaquaTest create latency=406
QuaquaTest total startup latency=819
Warning: class ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXApplication couldn't load library "quaqua". java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no quaqua in java.library.path
user chose Continue
```

Comment: `Include the directory /System/Library/Java in the class path., what does this means ?

Comment: For development purposes, see [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/laf.html). I generally use [http://www.virtualbox.org/](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instead.

Comment: thats perfect!!! using this i can alter the look and feel.. but sad thing is that quaqua wont allow us to put the commercial application on linux platform :(

Comment: Well, it's Apple that wouldn't approve; nor would Microsoft, etc.

Comment: for that virtualbox we need to have image of the OS to boot rite ?

Comment: so is there any good professionally looking LAF available that we can use it in cross platforms ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know; I usually stick to the bundled L&Fs.